# Amazon Redshift stored procedure call

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_test1(p_1 varchar)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS $$   
DECLARE
V_TEST integer := 0;
BEGIN
    
    select count(*) 
    from mytab
    into V_TEST
    WHERE X =P_1;

RAISE NOTICE 'COUNT IS:(%)',V_TEST;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
 null;
END;  
$$
;
```

In Amazon Redshift, can I not call this stored proc in this way ?

call proc_test1(p_1 => 'x')

also, why does RAISE with a semicolon fails ? the below error handler says RAISE; - the error i get is invalid operation: syntax error at or near ;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE risk.proc_test1(p_1 varchar)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS $$   
DECLARE
V_TEST integer := 0;
BEGIN
    
    select count(*) 
    from risk.mytab
    into V_TEST
    WHERE X =P_1;

RAISE NOTICE 'COUNT IS:(%)',V_TEST;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
RAISE;
END;  
$$
;
```

Comment: Is this related to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67987599/aws-redshift-cluster-table-vs-spectrum-what-to-choose You should take the advice of the commenter there - for 15K records a year this is the wrong database to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
call proc_test1(p_1 => 'x')
```

Are you asking about the syntax of calls, or are you asking about named parameters?

The doc doesn't mention it so no it isn't supported.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CALL_procedure.html

I guess with regards to the `RAISE` error, you are missing required parameters

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-statements.html#r_PLpgSQL-messages-errors

```
RAISE level 'format' [, variable [, ...]];
```

All of these things are in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you , follow up question, i need to store timestamp column in redshift table and do a default of current timestamp , however I don't see current_timestamp in aws documentation, whereas select current_timestamp returns value in my dbeaver

Comment: You really need to learn to do internet research. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/Date_functions_header.html

Comment: @Guatam can you please consider marking this question and your other questions as correct if they helped you.